# How to replace regex pattern with a new term in sed?

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to replace all terms that start with a hashtag with a new term

I'm using sed but there seems to be a syntax error

```
sed 's/#[a-zA-Z0-9]+/replacement/g' terms
```

How can I correct my syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` supports a "basic regular expression" (BRE) which does not offer the `+` as a special operator.

A correct replacement for `+` would be

```
sed 's/#[[:alnum:]]\{1,\}/replacement/g'
```

or

```
sed 's/#[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]]*/replacement/g'
```

`GNU sed` and recent `BSD sed` offer "extended regular expression" (ERE) matching:

```
sed -E 's/#[[:alnum:]]+/replacement/g'
```

(although with `GNU sed` you should probably use `-r` since `-E` is currently undocumented)

and they also offer `\+` as an extension to `BRE`,

```
sed 's/#[[:alnum:]]\+/replacement/g'
```

If you require portability you should stick with the `BRE` of regular `sed`.

---

@user784637 I used `[[:alnum:]]` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. This would also match letters with diacriticals for example.

```
$ printf "%s\n" ë è é | grep '[a-zA-Z0-9]'
$
```

vs.

```
$ printf "%s\n" ë è é | grep '[[:alnum:]]'
ë
è
é
$
```

You could use either that suits your needs..

Comment: Open the pod bay doors, HAL

Answer (score 1):

On my version of sed, `+` doesn't do anything useful.  You should use `*` instead.

Comment: That did the trick.  on `egrep -E` the plus operate repeats the previous term 1 or more times while asterisk repeats the previous term 0 or more times.